# Loading a list page in Symfony 1.4 taking ~10 secs on new server

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, mysql5

I moved from an old sever running centOS on a managed hoster to a new one running Ubuntu in AWS.

Post the move I've noticed that the page that loads a list of items is now taking ~10-12 secs to render (sometimes even up to 74secs). This was never noticed on the old server. I used newrelic to look at what was taking so long and found that the sfPHPView->render() was taking 99% of the time. From nerelic there is approximately ~500 calls to the DB to render the page.

The page is a list of ideas, with each idea a row. I use the $idea->getAccounts()->getSlug() ability of Doctrine 1.2. Where accounts is another table linked to the idea as a foreign relation. This is called several times for each idea row. A partial is not currently used to hold the code for each row element.

1. Is there a performance advantage to using a partial for the row element? (ignoring for now the benefit of code maintability)
2. What is best practice for referencing data connected via a foreign relation? I'm surprised that a call is made to the DB everytime $idea->getAccounts()->getSlug() is called.
3. Is there anything obvious in ubuntu that would otherwise be making sfPHPView->render() run slower than centOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you my thought

- When using a partial for a row element, it's more easy to put it in cache, because you can affine the caching by partial.
- Because you don't *explicit* define the relation when making the query, Doctrine won't hydrate all elements with the relation. For this point, you can manually define relations you want to hydrate. Then, your call `$idea->getAccounts()->getSlug()` won't perform a new query every time.

```php
$q = $this->createQuery();
$q->leftJoin('Idea.Account');
```

- No idea for the point 3.

---

**PS**: for the point 2, it's very common to have lots of queries in admin gen when you want to display an information from a relation (in the list view). The solution is to define the method to retrieve data:

In your generator.yml:

```
list:
  table_method: retrieveForBackendList
```

In the IdeaTable:

```
public function retrieveForBackendList(Doctrine_Query $q)
{
  $rootAlias = $q->getRootAlias();
  $q->leftJoin($rootAlias . '.Account');

  return $q;
}
```

Comment: Hi @j0k that is very useful to know about the explicit join. So if I do this: $q = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Ideas I')->where(some criteria)->leftjoin('I.Account')->execute(); will explicitly include the Account data? Do you know of any other speed ups for sfPHPView->renderFile()?

Comment: yep, if you explicit add the leftJoin Doctrine will hydrate results with the Account data for each row. I don't know other speed up for `renderFile`.

Answer (score 0):

Though I would add what else I did to improve the speed of page load in addition to jOk's recommendations.

In addition to the explicit joins I did the following:

1. Switched to returning a DQL Query object which was then passed to Doctrine's [`paginator`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/utilities.html#pagination)
2. Changed from using `include_partial()` to PHP's `include()` which reduced the object creation time of `include_partial()`
3. [Hydrate](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/data-hydrators.html) the data from the DB as an array instead of an object
4. Removed some foreach loops by doing more leftJoins in the DB
5. Used result & query caching to reduce the number of DB calls
6. Used view caching to reduce PHP template generation time

Interestingly, by doing 1 to 4 it made 5 and 6 more effective and easier to implement. I think there is something to be said for improving your code before jumping in with caching.